# Updating one-to-Many relationships Failed on SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two entities . The First is "Order"

```
public class Order : EntityBase
{

    public Guid ClientKey { get; set; }
    public Guid EmployeeKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DeliveryType DeliveryType { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public bool SoftDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<JourneyOrder> JourneyOrder { get; set; }
    **public virtual ICollection<Item> Items
    { get; set; }**
    public virtual ICollection<ItemToBeFactored> ItemToBeFactored
    { get; set; }


    public Order() : base()
    {

        Items = new HashSet<Item>();
        ItemToBeFactored = new HashSet<ItemToBeFactored>();
        JourneyOrder = new HashSet<JourneyOrder>();
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;

    }
}
```

and the second is : "Item":

```
public class Item : EntityBase
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double width { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public Guid OrderKey { get; set; }

    **public Order CustomerOrder { get; set; }**
}
```

I am trying to update the navigation property in Order entity in this code :

```
var order = _context.Orders.Where(x => x.Key.Equals(new Guid("67972aa1-2bb4-4916-b48b-1fdc3c2f5db9"))).Include(x => x.Items).
            First();

  order.Items = new List<Item> 
  {
        new Item {  Color = "Green", width = 20d }
  };

  _context.SaveChanges();
```

I got this repetitive error :

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded

The updating is working on "one-to-on" property but nut on one-many navigation property !!

Update:

I could use update in a dummy way !!
First: I cleared the items from order,
then

```
_context.Items.add( new Item { OrderKey = order.Key, Color = "Blue", width = 240d }) 
then _context.SaveChanges();
```

But it is not an efficient way !! –

Comment: Usually you don't overwrite the collection properties. Does it work when you add the new item directly via `order.Items.Add()` without setting the `order.Items` property with your own list? If not, what is the error message you get now?

Comment: @Progman  I got the same exception !!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It should generate the exception you get.

Comment: I could use update in dummy way !!
first: I cleared the items from order, then 
_context.Items.add(  new Item { OrderKey = order.Key, Color = "Blue", width = 240d })

then _context.SaveChanges(); 
But it is not an efficient way !!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are loading the `Order` as follows:

```
var order = _context.Orders.Find(new Guid("67972aa1-2bb4-4916-b48b-1fdc3c2f5db9"));
```

Its not loading the `Items` of the `Order` along with it and hence its not being tracked and updated!

So you have to load the `Items` along with `Order` as follows and then modify the `Item` collection:

```
var order = _context.Orders.Where(o => o.Id == new Guid("67972aa1-2bb4-4916-b48b-1fdc3c2f5db9"))
                           .Include(o => o.Items).FirstOrDefault(); // I assumed your `Order` primary key name is `Id`

  order.Items = new List<Item> 
  {
        new Item {  Color = "Green", width = 20d }
  };

  _context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Actually I have tried this solution , and a lot of solutions like :
    //_context.Orders.Attach(order1);
   //_context.Entry(order1).(e => e.Items).IsModified = true;
But still not working !!

Comment: Does not work it? Use my solution exactly. Surely it will work.

Comment: No ^_^ , same exception

Comment: Bro ,  I am a developer for years , I have already used your solution ^_^ , but actually it's not working , because I have tried  it before posting this question

Comment: I think the problem is not in Linq or in the query ,maybe in  the context !! in the ModelBuilder

Comment: @MohammadAhmadAbdullah Even the problem is anywhere but your posted code will also not work. So problem may be in both places. I have given the solution according to what you posted here.

Comment: @MohammadAhmadAbdullah Check your object, does it pass Primary Key Null. This Exception is Generally due to this reason only.

Comment: I have checked the key , it has a value !!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is call Context.Update(*pass your object as parameter here*), see below

```
var order = _context.Orders.Where(x => x.Key.Equals(new Guid("67972aa1-2bb4-4916-b48b-1fdc3c2f5db9"))).Include(x => x.Items).
            First();

  order.Items = new List<Item> 
  {
        new Item {  Color = "Green", width = 20d }
  };
  
_context.Update(order);
  _context.SaveChanges();
```

*This works perfect in the very same instance of DbContext you created*. Got it to work on my side perfect